# forecasting with holt-winters model

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, forecasting, holtwinters

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing

df =pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\mysqlconnection\mul.csv",
                 index_col='finalYears')

)
df.index.freq = 'M'
train, test = df.iloc[:20, 0], df.iloc[20:, 0]
model = ExponentialSmoothing(train, seasonal='mul', seasonal_periods=4).fit()
pred = model.predict(start=test.index[0], end=test.index[-1])

plt.plot(train.index, train, label='Train')
plt.plot(test.index, test, label='Test')
plt.plot(pred.index, pred, label='Holt-Winters')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

I tried forecasting with holt-winters model as shown above but I keep getting this error.
**the error occur at pred line says that  "'The `start` argument could not be matched to a location related to the index of the data."  ,  how i want to handle this error?**

This is my data. i group the data into quarter of the year   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHiGh.png)

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/generated/statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing.predict.html#statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing.predict) it seems like the start,end have to be int,str, or datetime.  If I do

```
start = 20
end = test.shape[0]+20
pred = model.predict(start=start, end=end)
```

then the prediction runs. The read_csv may have converted your index column to something other than int/str/datetime.

Comment: thanks for reply :) But it give me with another error which is plotting error which says that  .  Error "IndexError: tuple index out of range. can you help me with this ?

Comment: check the lengths of your train, test, and pred vectors, maybe one or more has length zero?

Comment: hey, i already confused which one i need to change :( did the error related to this line ? df.index.freq = 'M' train, test = df.iloc[:20, 0], df.iloc[20:, 0] Basically , i want to test start from line 20 and below in my data file ( provided above). i hope you can help me to fix this prob :)